# Scoped storage / Android 11, targetSdkVersion = 30 / save non-media files

Tags: android

Is there any way to save → **non-media** files to `/Documents` or `/Download`on targetSdk=30 (without `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission`)?

[image: ![grafik|690x215, 75%](upload://cKokg60TqPI0YkCwUe0Xx4Pqx6n.png)]

See [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/scope-storage-myths-ca6a97d7ff37). (Are they referring to folders (`/Documents /Downloads`) in the ASD → app-specific dir?)

See also here:
https://androidexplained.github.io/android/android11/scoped-storage/2020/09/29/file-saving-android-11.html

This Scoped storage stuff is really confusing.
It would be nice if someone would shed a little more light into the darkness here.

Comment: Yes you can do it. Apparently you did not even try. But a /Documents directory does not exist. Or a /Download. It's /storage/emulated/0/Documents . But if you use mediastore to save your files in those folders you do not need to know full path.

Comment: Of course I meant → /storage/emulated/0/Documents/. But how do you save a non-media file (e.g. a text file) there (with targetSdk=30 on a device with API > 28)? I couldn't. I only can save a text file in the ASD (app-specific dir).

Comment: You can save any file there on an Android 11 device. Nothing special. Show your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't work with Android Studio, but with AppInventor and Kodular. But if you are absolutely sure that it is basically possible to save a non-media file in /storage/emulated/0/Documents/ (without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission), then thank you for the information. If you had a simple test APK it would be very helpful to check it out.

Comment: See here: https://androidexplained.github.io/android/android11/scoped-storage/2020/09/29/file-saving-android-11.html